# No sound in Google Chrome after motherboard upgrade

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, audio, motherboard

I recently replaced my motherboard and I have a weird issue with Google Chrome. When I open it, I can normally play a video on youtube for example and all is normal. But if I pause it for 5 - 10 seconds, or if I select another video or anything, sound stops working completely in Chrome.

I can fix it again by restarting chrome and then again I have sound for the first video or few seconds. But then sound stops again.

So to play 3 youtube videos I have to restart chrome before watching every one of them which gets annoying.

It already happened to me about half a year ago when I first replaced my motherboard. I solved it by reinstalling Windows. But since I did it recently and went through all the installing and setting of all the apps and games, I would really like to just solve this issue.

The issue is just in Chrome, everything else works without any problem (games, other browsers and apps etc.).

What I already tried:
I tried uninstalling and installing audio drivers from the MB manufacturer. All the chrome settings of pages where you can mute the pages etc. Uninstalling and installing Chrome, some regedit stuff from [answers here](https://superuser.com/questions/687577/google-chrome-missing-from-volume-mixer). Nothing helped.

I have Windows 10. The sound works from all MB outputs in every other app, just not in Chrome after 10 seconds or one video/audio. It even shows up in the volume mixer in Windows for the first video, but then for every next video/audio it does not appear there.

I know that reinstalling Windows would solve the issue, but at this point I would rather start using different browser than doing that.

I'm surprised that I did not find other people with this issue, since I replaced my MB two times and everytime I had this issue so it seems to me that it happens everytime.

Comment: Do you use the onboard audio or a PCI sound card? Did you change for exactly the same motherboard every time? If yes, what is your motherboard model? With all the trouble you've had I'd have bought a new sound card already...

Comment: I changed it for upgrade of my PC, not for any issue. I also found an old USB soundcard, so I tried that just now and even with external sound card (so making sure it is not MB drivers) the problem persists.

Comment: But I just solved it, will answer the question.

Comment: Great, post your answer so others will know. ^^

Comment: Reinstall Chrome?

Comment: Already tried, its funny that it was not enough to somehow reset chrome default audio output. I even searched AppData for leftover files. I enabled logging and found that there was an error with output logged and that it used fallback fake audio output which caused the no sound issue. Rest is in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I just tried an external USB sound card and the problem was still present, so it was not a problem with the MB drivers or anything.

So I clicked on the speaker icon in the tray and clicked Open sound settings as usual. It looks different now, see image below (just an ilustration, not mine, since I have my windows in Czech, which would not help that much):

**Old sound settings**

[image: Old sound settings]

**New sound settings**
[image: New sound settings]

And there I noticed in the bottom of the page "App volume and device preferences". I swear I never saw this option before. And in there (it is basically a more fancy version of Volume mixer) I saw Chrome, as I was playing a first video where I had sound. There you can select Output and Input for the given app. The Chrome app had Output "blank", so I just set it to default and it finally works again.

Such a simple issue but it took me several hours to fix, not to mention that the first time I did whole Windows reinstall just because of this.